# C# How To Access Dynamic Variable Properties in C# and Razor

Tags: c#, sql, variables, dynamic, razor

I have the name of a stored procedure stored in a database (and a couple of views). At run time I query the database and then run the needed query. Since I don't know the field names of the query nor do I have a known object to store the results to I use a dynamic variable

```
dynamic results = Respository.GetTableContents(); 
// not exactly the code but it conveys the point
```

The table would have an unknown number of fields, but for this example the field names are

```
Id, FirstName, Lastname  //(this is what the table would be returning) 

// Normally stored to a list of the model type
List<Users> resultsFromTable = ...
```

The resulting dynamic data can be accessed by

```
foreach(var r in result)
{
    string name = r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName;
    //.... Do something with the code, etc.
}
```

That is great if you know the property names. I don't know the property names.

**How do I access the data of the dynamic variable without knowing the property name?**

*My main goal would be to use this in the view (razor).*

Maybe I have approached the problem wrong and there is a better way. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure what your `Respository.GetTableContents()` returns, but I would use a simple `System.Data.DataTable` Then I would just use `foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)`. In this case you'd get DataColumn type which can be used to get `ColumnName` property of the column, including its `DataType`, length, and of course its value

Comment: If your `Respository.GetTableContents()` returns some class based on ExpandoObject you could cast it to `IDictionary<string, Object>`

Comment: @cha This is what I thought would work, but we just implemented this fancy database repository. Hopefully the answer below will work out. If not then I might have to persuade them for this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to use `System.Reflection`. Try this:

```
foreach (var r in results)
{
    string name, trimmedName = "";
    if (r.GetType() == typeof(ExpandoObject))
    { 
        name = ((IDictionary<string,object>)r).ToList()
            .Aggregate<KeyValuePair<string,object>, string>("", (s, p) =>
        {
            return s + " " + p.Value;
        });
        trimmedName = name.Trim();
    }
    else
    {
        PropertyInfo[] ps = r.GetType().GetProperties();
        name = ps.Aggregate<PropertyInfo, string>("", (s, p) =>
        {
            return s + " " + p.GetValue(r);
        });
        trimmedName = name.Trim();
    }
    // use the trimmedName 
    Console.WriteLine(trimmedName);
}
```

[EDIT] Based on @pwas' suggestio, here's an version of he code with an improved Cyclomatic Complexity:

```
foreach (var r in results)
{
    ProcessResult(r);
}
```

Where `ProcessResult` has 2 overloads:

```
static void ProcessResult(ExpandoObject r)
{
    string name, trimmedName = "";
    name = ((IDictionary<string, object>)r).ToList()
        .Aggregate<KeyValuePair<string, object>, string>("", (s, p) =>
        {
            return s + " " + p.Value;
        });
    trimmedName = name.Trim();
    FurtherProcess(trimmedName);
}

static void ProcessResult(object r)
{
    string name, trimmedName = "";
    PropertyInfo[] ps = r.GetType().GetProperties();
    name = ps.Aggregate<PropertyInfo, string>("", (s, p) =>
    {
        return s + " " + p.GetValue(r);
    });
    FurtherProcess(trimmedName);
}

private static void FurtherProcess(string trimmedName)
{
    Console.WriteLine(trimmedName);
}
```

Here is the improvement:

```
Type        Maintainability     Cyclomatic
            Index               Complexity
Program     54                  24
// After code optimization
Program     69                  16
```

Comment: Nice, but I'd split processing `r` to separate methods in order to avoid `if` statement. For example: prepare method `public void ProcessResult(ExpandoObject eo) { \\ your code }` and `public void ProcessResult(object o) { \\ your code }` and then call it `foreach (var r in result) ProcessResult(r)`. In this case, `r` is dynamic, so its type will be resolved at the runtime and proper overloaded method will be used. Then you could easily add method for processing specific type.  My little digression :)

Comment: @pwas, very nice suggestion, I'll update my answer based on it.

Comment: @pwas *In this case, r is dynamic, so its type will be resolved at the runtime and proper overloaded method will be used.* I had no idea dynamic works like this. Nice!